# Cassandra auto scaling

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Want to deploy datastax Cassandra cluster(Multiple DC's - in multiple regions) in google cloud compute engine with auto scale capability.

I have deployed datastax cassandra cluster in google cloud but not sure how to configure auto scaling capability .

In google cloud compute engines auto scaling is only possible with managed instances group. I.e. all the instances should be in a particular region. Since cassandra cluster deployed in multiple regions, do we need maintain separate auto scaling(managed instance template) feature for each region.

Do we need to use google cloud auto scaling concept or datastax has its own in build one?

How to add new VM's to cluster if we provision a VM's based on google cloud managed instance group concept.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain separate auto scaling.

And Let Google Cloud maintain the auto scaling because the machines that need to be added are obviously handled by Google Cloud. DataStax Enterprise has no way of doing it automatically.

I don't know each and every step (for Google Cloud) but when you spin up a machine,you can keep a script to run which starts Cassandra with some set of 'seeds'.

Comment: Thanks Sreekar. Comparing Cassandra in cloud and local. Does cluster load balance automatically when we add the new VM's or need to do manually. In peak hours only need additional resources remaining time minimum nodes are sufficient for me. Does spin down also need to have our own mechanism?

Comment: Yes, spin up and spin down needs some mechanism but it's quite simple to do it in Cassandra. Nodetool can be used to spin down. When you spin up, then make sure your machine joins the cluster with proper 'seeds' and when you spin down, make sure you are properly 'decommissioning' in shutdown sequence.

Comment: To specifically answer your question, Yes, cluster load balances automatically as soon as the new VM joined the cluster properly (which takes some time based on your data size). After spin down also, Cassandra load balances automatically. In fact this is one of main selling points of Cassandra.